# Open source CMS system on asp.net

Tags: asp.net, open-source, content-management-system

We are in the process of building corporate website where they need basic web content search and document upload and search on the same.

I would like to know if any open source CMS tool out there which will allow us to do that. 
Mojo protal - is soemthing i am looking at it. Please let us know feedback on the tool. We are looking very simple CMS features.

Technolgies we are planning to use 
ASP.NET 3.5 and SQL 2005 or SQL 2008

Answer (score 3):

Check out N2CMS also.

It is also highly regarded as an opensource ASP.NET CMS.

http://n2cms.com

Answer (score 2):

The best open source ASP.Net CMS i have used is Umbraco.  It is easy to use and set up.  Quick to restyle to your own HTML template and can be extended using XSLT for simple things and C# is there for the more complex this you want to do.

The website with more details is available at: [Umbraco](http://umbraco.org/)

The Main features are:

**For Editors**

- Beautiful, user-friendly interface
- Integrated WYSIWYG Editor
- Support for editing in Microsoft Word
- Versioned and scheduled publishing

**For Developers**

- Full support for own .NET Controls
- Documented API
- Use any .NET Language like c# or VB.NET
- Full source code available (open source)

**For Designers**

- No limits to design
- Super simple template engine - based on ASP.Net Master Pages
- Full support for web standards
- Full support for accessibility standards

Comment: Isn't this XSLT-based? I mean, there's no DB, correct?

Comment: You can choose to use SQL Server 2005 for storage.

Comment: I am looking for free software.

Comment: The core software is Open Source so you can use it for free - the download is available on CodePlex (http://umbraco.codeplex.com/).  They also sell a pro version with commercial support should you need it.

Answer (score 1):

try mojoportal, easy to use and easy to develop, you can make template for it useing artisteer